# My button moves when I click it. How do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

The pause/play button moves when I click it. How do I fix that?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".button");
if (btn === null) {
  throw new Error('could not find button');
}
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.classList.toggle("paused");
  return false;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --pauseButtonhight: 16px;
  --pauseButtonwidth: 13px;
  --pauseButtonborder: 8px;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: var(--pauseButtonhight);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7083d8;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--pauseButtonborder) 0 var(--pauseButtonborder) var(--pauseButtonwidth);
}

.button.paused {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px var(--pauseButtonwidth);
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="playspersecond">Updates per second: </label>
  <input type="number" id="playspersecond" value="5" min="0" max="10" />
  <button class="button" id="play"></button>
</div>
```

The button moves up and down when you press it, and moves the text next to it as well.
I think this has something to do with how I am drawing the button in the different states, but I am new to CSS/HTML so I don't know what to do.
This is an edited version of [this pause button](https://css-tricks.com/making-pure-css-playpause-button/)

If you have a better/correct way of doing a pause/play button, that would work as well.

Comment: I have never seen the border property used to make basic shapes like this, very clever! However, imo this type of thing is the perfect use case for simple inline SVGs. In addition to being a lot more semantic, it might even be a little less code in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment of the button to `middle` (or `top`):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".button");
if (btn === null) {
  throw new Error('could not find button');
}
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.classList.toggle("paused");
  return false;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --pauseButtonhight: 16px;
  --pauseButtonwidth: 13px;
  --pauseButtonborder: 8px;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: var(--pauseButtonhight);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7083d8;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--pauseButtonborder) 0 var(--pauseButtonborder) var(--pauseButtonwidth);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button.paused {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px var(--pauseButtonwidth);
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="playspersecond">Updates per second: </label>
  <input type="number" id="playspersecond" value="5" min="0" max="10" />
  <button class="button" id="play"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.button` class.

Like this.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".button");
if (btn === null) {
  throw new Error('could not find button');
}
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.classList.toggle("paused");
  return false;
});
```

```css
:root {
  --pauseButtonhight: 16px;
  --pauseButtonwidth: 13px;
  --pauseButtonborder: 8px;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: var(--pauseButtonhight);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7083d8;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--pauseButtonborder) 0 var(--pauseButtonborder) var(--pauseButtonwidth);
}

.button.paused {
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px var(--pauseButtonwidth);
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="playspersecond">Updates per second: </label>
  <input type="number" id="playspersecond" value="5" min="0" max="10" />
  <button class="button" id="play"></button>
</div>
```